# why bevel modifiers offset is not working properly with cylinder object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

why blender modifier's offset is not working properly.

[image]

blender file
[image]

Comment: I guess because at one point it prevent the vertices to overlap and depending on your topology it may overlap quickly? But maybe share your file?

Comment: The clamp overlap option is active, thus the offset will be internally reduced to stay in the save range. To check where the problem lies, deactivate the clamp and adjust the offset. There will be artifacts appearing and those places are to be adjusted before the bevel can be used generating clean results.

Comment: thank you moonboots,xylvier for replying for my question.i uploaded my blender file.  As you say turn off clamp  overlap cause artifacts is correct. but consider modelling with non-destructive way  how  i clean up this artifacts without applying boolean modifier